# Is a question deleted automatically once the downvote threshold has been met?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, closed-questions, deleted-questions

I recently asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352555/is-the-stack-exchange-site-super-user-for-windows-only?noredirect=1#comment1178578_352555) in the wrong place (which has since been closed), and as a result my reputation has suffered a bombardment of downvotes. Ok, oops, wrong place, but now I cant even delete the question:

[image]

Of course I understand that irrelevant material should be moved, deleted or migrated, but since there was an answer to this question I am not able to do any of this. It seems there is a threshold of downvotes required for a post to be deleted. Currently my question requires one more downvote for this threshold to be met, but I ask, then what happens? Is a post deleted automatically once this threshold has been met? What about the answer that someone tool the time to write?

Is there any recourse I can take to make this right, or do I have to watch my reputation drain from a simple mistake of where to post? I have flagged the question to either be moved to [the right place](https://meta.superuser.com/), or to be deleted but so far nothing has changed, other than my reputation going down.

Comment: I just cast the final delete vote on the question (as a 20k+ user, I can vote to delete closed questions scoring -3 immediately after they're closed), so this shouldn't be an issue now.

Comment: It might be visible to you and to any mods and users of high rep (if they already have a record of the URL), but it's now invisible to me and most.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog thanks for that! I am still curious as to whether a question is automatically closed at the threshold though =)

Comment: Please research before considering asking on SE sites & if you do need to ask summarize your research in your post.